80s or 90s sci-fi book with evil scientist trying to recapture boy with special abilities
I'm searching for a 80s or 90s sci-fi book I read as a kid. An evil scientist type is trying to capture or recapture a boy. He lost his memory and it turns out has special abilities the evil man is after. While running he manifests his power to teleport and he begins to try and figure out who he is and why he is being chased. I believe his family also has special abilities and protected him as a child.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
